# Wrong path to cordova_plugins.js file (ios only)

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have a problem with file cordova_plugins loading. Sometimes, app detects wrong path to cordova.js file, something like `file:///` and that's it. But right path is `file:///Users/artur/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7C909069-BA08-45D2-A2C0-F3D8DA453879/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C6E14DD3-9F29-4973-9516-D1F819D8A000/AppName/www/cordova_plugins.js`.

cordova.js file loads correctly even with wrong path.

> Ionic 1, Angular 1

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:
    Cordova Platforms : ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework   : unknown

System:
    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    Node       : v8.9.3
    npm        : 5.5.1 
    OS         : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b 

Environment Variables:

Misc:
    backend : pro
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. All that I needed to do is set html5mode.enabled to "false":

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
     enabled: false
});
```